# Почему не используется индекс?

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть поле:

```
pp enum('T','S','E','U','AC','AT','M','MA','BA','MC','BC','D')
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
KEY pp (pp)
```

Если делать так:

```
select * from tbl_invoices where (pp is null or pp in ('S'));
```

То видно, что в запросе используется key:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tbl_invoices
         type: ref_or_null
possible_keys: pp
          key: pp
      key_len: 2
          ref: const
         rows: 83064
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

А если делать так:

```
select * from tbl_invoices where (pp is null or pp in ('S','D'));
```

То key уже не используется:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tbl_invoices
         type: ALL
possible_keys: pp
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 321844
        Extra: Using where
```

Подскажите, как переделать запрос, что-бы во втором случае тоже использовался key?

Comment: А покажите планы для каждой части `where`. Т.е. интересует сколько записей с `pp IS NULL`, `pp = 'S'` и `pp = 'D'`. Вообще, это нормальное поведение - выборка по индексу приводит к произвольному чтению с диска и если почти все записи соответствуют условию, то намного быстрее будет проходить последовательный просмотр записей.

Comment: Ага, я понял. А есть ли смысл иногда настаивать на своём `force index (pp)` или можно считать, что оптимизатор mysql всегда лучше меня знает?

Comment: Оптимизатор не всегда правильно оптимизирует, но чаще всего показывает весьма не плохие результаты (и еще чаще - лучше вас видит всю картину, т.к. там не только произвольное чтение), поэтому я бы не стал изменять его поведение. Но реальная база и запросы у вас под рукой, поэтому вы можете посмотреть как поведет себя план если давать ему различные подсказки (типа того же `force index`). Если используется MyISAM, то, возможно, имеет смысл сделать `ANALYZE TABLE`, чтобы пересчитать кардинальность индекса (для InnoDB вроде не поможет)

Comment: @BOPOH Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, это только предположение, т.к. я не видел общего числа записей для каждого значения ключа

Answer (score 2):

У вас два разных случая, в первом случае, оптимизатор безошибочно распознает ситуацию `pp = 'S'` - сравнение значения с константой о чем отчет `EXPLAIN` и сообщает строкой

```
type: ref_or_null
ref: const
```

Это означает, что для поиска вообще не будут использоваться данные таблицы - результат будет найдет в индексе и по нему возвращены данные из таблицы.

Во втором случае, ситуация сложнее, так как избавиться от `IN` оптимизатору не удастся. Я получил другие результаты `EXPLAIN`, СУБД сообщила что будет использовать индекс в покрывающем режиме

```
type: range
ref: NULL
```

Т.е. индекс использоваться будет, но не для поиска, а для сортировки данных. То, что мы получаем разные результаты - это нормально. Дело в том, что оптимизатор принимает решение в зависимости от размера таблиц и статистики запросов. Почему оптимизацией запросов и рекомендуют заниматься на боевом, разогретом сервере, так как статистика на холодном сервере с той же самой базой данных может быть другой.

Теперь к вашему вопросу. Обратите внимание, что во втором запросе у вас довольно большое количество извлекаемых записей `rows: 321844`, вероятно, оно сопоставимо с количеством записей в самой таблице `tbl_invoices` в этом случае оптимизатор может решить, что смысла сортировать таблицу вообще нет и полный скан несортированной таблицы будет выполнен быстрее, чем предварительная сортировка (и не факт, что в оперативной памяти, может на диске) с последующим неполным сканом отсортированных данных.